# $watch on two-way binding in directive not invoked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a simple paginator directive. The idea is that i have a dynamic table based on a category. Eg: 
Category-> Fruits, table will have Apple, Bananas, Oranges etc
Category -> Vegetables, table will have Spinach, Cauliflower and so on

I am trying to build a dynamic paginator directive

The code is below

```
myApp.directive("myPaginator",function(){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
    replace:true,
        scope:{
            displayPage :"=",
        numPages : "="
        },
        link:function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){                

        scope.$watch(scope.numPages, function(){
           console.log("New num pages:"+scope.numPages);
           scope.nPages = parseInt(scope.numPages,10);      
           scope.pages=[];
           for (var i=0;i<scope.nPages;i++) {
                scope.pages.push({value:''+(i+1),text:'Page '+(i+1)});
           }
        }, true);
        console.log("Watch is bound");

        },
        controller:function($scope){        
            $scope.onPrevClick=function(newIndex){
                $scope.displayPage = $scope.displayPage -1;
            }

            $scope.onNextClick=function(newIndex){
                $scope.displayPage = $scope.displayPage +1;
            }

        $scope.onFirstClick=function(newIndex){
                $scope.displayPage = 1;
            }

            $scope.onPrevClick=function(newIndex){
                $scope.displayPage = $scope.numPages;
            }

        },
        template:"<div style='clear:both' class='pagination'><ul >"+
        "<li> <a ng-click=\"\">First</a></li>"+
        "<li ><a ng-click=\"\">Previous</a></li>"+
        "<li ><a ng-click=\"\">Page :<select ng-model='displayPage' "+
        "   ng-options='option.value as option.text for option in pages' ng-change=\"gotoPage()\">"+
        "</select></a></li>"+
        "<li ><a ng-click=\"\">Next</a></li>"+
        "<li ><a ng-click=\"\">Last</a></li>"+
                "</ul></div>"
    };

})
```

usage

```
<div my-paginator num-pages='numPages' display-page='currPage'></div>
```

The numPages get changed every time user picks a new category. The problem I am facing is the $watch on the numPages is never invoked even if the value is changed in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to watch a scope element is

```
scope.$watch('numPages', function () {
    // ...
});
```